# How does $x$ change to $X$ in this formula but not $y$ to $Y$?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

How does $x$ change to $X$ in this formula but not $y$ to $Y$?  Can someone explain to me?

Note: $X$ is a continuous random variable with PDF $f_X(x)$.

[image: eq]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking... there are four different quantities involved in the last formula, namely two real numbers $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and two random variables $X, Y: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ that are related by $Y=g(X)$, or more explicitly, by $Y(\omega)=g(X(\omega))$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. Now, unfolding the definition of c.d.f. for $Y$, we have $$ F_Y(y)=\mathbf{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbf{P}(g(X)\leq y).$$ Then, provided $g$ is increasing and has an inverse $h=g^{-1}$, $$=\mathbf{P}(X\leq h(y))=F_X(h(y)),$$ where we invoked the definition of c.d.f. again at the last step.

Comment: And let me clarify that all the intermediate steps above hold because we have equalities at the level of events: $$\{Y\leq y\}=\{g(X)\leq y\}=\{X\leq h(y)\}.$$ More precisely, using the set-builder notation, these events can be written as $$\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)\leq y\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq h(y)\}.$$

Comment: I wanted to ask why they don't put it as $\mathbf P(g(X) \leq y)= \mathbf P(x \leq h(Y))$.

Comment: Judging by the context, I suspect that you have some misunderstanding on the concept of random variables and events. In the image, there is no magic like 'replacing $x$ by $y$ gives you something' involved. It is a consequence of the following logical equivalences: \begin{align*}Y\leq y &\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad g(X)\leq y\tag{$\because$ by the def. of $Y$} \\&\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad X\leq g^{-1}(y)\tag{$\because$ $g$ is monotonically inc.}\end{align*}

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for the enlightenment!

Comment: How do you remember all that off the top of your head?